# Returning a Vector in R

Tags: r, vector

Beginning R programmer here. I'm trying to run a function with the argument being the number of samples (user-defined) and the output being a vector of means of those samples.

Here is what I have so far, however, I only get one mean value returned. How do I alter the formula so I get a vector of the means that is variable on the number the user inputs?

```
Pop1 <- rnorm(500, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.2)
My_Func <- function(Samples) {

  A <- sample(Pop1, size = 25, replace = TRUE)

  for (i in 1:Samples) {
    Means <- mean(A)
  }


  return(Means)
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is constantly assigning to the same variable. You will only get the value from the last iteration of the loop that way. You should perhaps look into the `replicate()` function to take repeated samples: `replicate(Samples, mean(sample(Pop1, size=25, replace=TRUE)))` (no explicit loop needed)

Comment: Thanks MrFlick! That seems to do the trick. Just for my own knowledge, how would I format the loop so it doesn't just return the same value, but returns the mean for the number of samples the user inputs?

Comment: That's something you would typically not use a loop for in R. To show the loop way would be teaching bad R habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a for loop it can be like this. As @MrFlick mentioned, avoid assingning the loop to the same variable. Include it into the loop.

```
Pop1 <- rnorm(500, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.2)

My_Func <- function(Samples) {
 Means = numeric(Samples)
 for (i in 1:Samples) {
 A <- sample(Pop1, size = 25, replace = TRUE)
 Means[i] <- mean(A)
 }
 return(Means)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rosapluesch! When I complete it this way, I enter My_Func(50) and it only returns 25 samples instead of the requested 50. I think is has to do with the size = 25 portion. But the code looks right to me. Any ideas?

Comment: No, the value of `Samples` (in your example 50) gives the number of loops and, thus, the number of values the function should return. I tried it and the function returned 50 values. Make sure that `Means = numeric(Samples)` and `for (i in 1:Samples)`.

Comment: However, you should have a look on the `replicate` function as well and try `replicate(Samples, mean(sample(Pop1, size=25, replace=TRUE)))` as MrFlick suggested cause this would be much more elegant!